# I can't get an arrayed object to follow bezier curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I've done this hundreds of times in 2.7x but in 2.81 I just can't get it to work no matter what I've tried. Sample file attached. I have a simple object I want to array to be, say, 5 kilometers long. I have bezier curve I want it to follow.  It just doesn't work and gets twisted and distorted in weird ways. What on earth is wrong... Same scale, same origins, same orientations. What I want is to make it follow the path of the bezier curve, like a road.

https://www47.zippyshare.com/v/gs2pl6wj/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that cause trouble:

**1. Array orientation** (little trouble)
Your array is facing the wrong way.
Just rotate it like this and set the *Relative offset* on the X axis.

[image]

**2. Curve radius** (big trouble)
The curve radius is set to 200 (waaay too high), which causes significant distortion.
Either change the curve radius to 1.
Or uncheck *Radius* in the curve properties.

Change curve radius to 1.
*Sidebar > Item > Mean Radius*
[image]

Or disable radius influence altogether
*Curve > Shape > Radius (uncheck)*.
[image]

Comment: That is not correct. Your object is flipped twice. It should look like road from above. Not that thing that is rotated 90 degrees and arrayed to wrong direction (Y+ should be forward).

Comment: The thing I just can't figure out is why is there some scaling when certain defoirmation axis and relative offset combinations are used. Where does that come from??

Comment: Do you have explanation why the Y-direction does not work?

Comment: Well, it works as expected. It's just it in the wrong direction - the width of the road, instead of length :).